# Gauge Label not showing decimals in reports

Tags: reporting-services, gauge

Is there a way to get the label of a gauge to show decimal places?  When I run the report, the data is like 99.999% but the label only shows 99%

Answer (score 1):

Change 'format' of the property in 'Properties' pane to be 0.00%

Generally if this is in a sub part of a gauge or chart you find that dotted rectangle part and then it's sub property.  EG: A gauge may have a 'Gauge Scale' and in it, it may have a 'LabelStyle' and that may expand to show a 'FormatString' I could set to be 0.00%.

Most of the times everything in SSRS related to displaying the presentation of a value of money, numbers, or a string of something is labeled 'Format' or format something.  Then you just need to know what to put in there to output to the way you want.  0.00% means (percent taken to place after .)